# How do I display only the title on an event in the calendar?

Tags: calendar, list-item

Right now, it is currently showing up as the date and the title but it is all mushed into one line.

I would like to change the default settings for all future events to be 
ALL DAY events, however every time I try to change it and open up a new event it still does not appear as all day event.

Is there any way to fix this so either the only thing that appears on a banner is the title or make every future default "New event" a all day event?

I have seen many tutorials on how to show more information, but none how to show less.

If someone knows, I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried modifying the column settings for the all day event column? Can you not set a default value there?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a bummer but you can't use the JSLink control on the Calender views (they don't load).  For any other list that would be my suggestion.

So in this case you can

1. use Script web part or a custom CSS file and include the following

   .ms-acal-time{
         display:none;
       }
2. Don't use the default calendar and instead use something like fullcalendar.io (requires a bit of work and some JavaScript knowledge to tie into SharePoint API).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and came up with an simple SharePoint Designer Workflow.

(It's in German, but I'm sure you get the idea)

[image]

First I check if a my column "duty" is one of the possible dropdown options.
Then I set the titel to the person and add also the duty. So the title looks like:

[image]

That's all.

Of cource set the workflow to **run on item created and modified**. This solutions works at least for me pretty good.

You can also check [afraIT.com](http://afrait.com) to get more information.